# jquery draggable moves on 30 degrees only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to have a selector that moves on a bar on 30 Degree angle , I have done some research on the web but I couldn't find any solution!.

I know that :

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ axis: 'x' });
```

will move it on x axis and :

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ axis: 'y' });
```

will move it on y axis but the question is how to move it on 30 degree angle only ?

[image]

I want to make this menu work .

[image]

Comment: I'm curious to see if this is doable or if you need some custom solution

Comment: As it shows in https://jqueryui.com/droppable/ there is no solution for this , so I think i need custom solution , not sure tho

Comment: Have you tried creating a diagonal element and setting it as the containment element?

Comment: Stupid me !, For sure that will work , lemme try it out .

Comment: it did work , i rotated the container 30 deg and it worked but it goes out of the container and come back inside then goes to border its not 30 deg sharp movement also no in a line :/

Comment: I liked the idea of using a rotated container, but jQuery UI seems to have some bugs with it.

Comment: ya .. but adding " position: relative; " to both container and selector solves the problem but still it isn't what i am looking for coz i need to do a menu like the image (updated!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, it's pretty easy!
All you have to do is control the position of your element in the `drag` event, and a bit of trigonometry will do the hard-work for you...

---

**Edited:**
Here is the [original answer](http://jsfiddle.net/66s337bs/)
Here is the [new one](http://jsfiddle.net/66s337bs/1/)

---

```js
var rad = Math.PI / 180;

$("#Handle").draggable(
{
    drag: function(event, ui)
    {
        var offset =
        {
            x: ui.offset.left - ui.originalPosition.left,
            y: ui.offset.top - ui.originalPosition.top
        };
        
        var distance = Math.sqrt(offset.x * offset.x + offset.y * offset.y);
        distance = Math.min(distance, 150);
        
        var angle;
        
             if (offset.y > 0) { angle = 90 * rad; } // Moving downwards
        else if (offset.x < 0) { angle = 210 * rad; } // Moving leftwards
        else                   { angle = 330 * rad; } // Moving rightwards
        
        ui.position.top = Math.sin(angle) * distance + ui.originalPosition.top;
        ui.position.left = Math.cos(angle) * distance + ui.originalPosition.left;
    }
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#Handle
{
    top: 150px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
}

#Background
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 200px;
}

#Background .bottom,
#Background .left,
#Background .right
{
    transform-origin: top left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#Background .bottom { transform: rotate(90deg); }
#Background .left { transform: rotate(210deg); }
#Background .right { transform: rotate(330deg); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="Background">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
</div>

<div id="Handle"></div>
```

Comment: thank you this is what i asked for , can i make this moves on 3 directions 30 degree , 150 degree and 90 degree , i have updated a picture for what i want to achieve , thanks for your help .

Comment: Interesting menu of yours... =D You can check if the `offset.x` and `offset.y` is positive or negative to change the angle lock... I'll try to update my fiddle

Comment: Seconds after posting the new code I noticed that if you drag the handle more than once it'll start from the wrong position. You'll need to store the initial position before dragging, and reset it back in the start or stop event (or somewhere else)

Comment: you probably want some static original position that is not detected in the draggable event. Because, if you let go of the square after moving it, it will be able to move from that point, not the original point

Comment: yea i noticed the problem ,, what if the red squire is moved then it snaps to the closest end or the center , then from there if it snaps we let it run anther code that it can move only in 1 direction till it snaps to the center it reset the option as it was ..

Comment: i took me really long time to solve it , if i change the "ui.originalPosition.top" and "ui.originalPosition.top" to the position of the handler which is "200" and "150" it solves the problem :) .. thank you for your help